# centralize python imports for docker builds efficency?

Tags: python, docker

Can I do this in python?

```
  $ file.py

  import project1.allmodules

  def task1():
      print "ok"

  def task2():

  ~/project1$  allmodules.py

  import sys, json, re, time,os
  from iron_mq import *
  from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
  from time import sleep
  from pythonlib.ltvlogger import *
  from requests
```

basically If i want to add a module to an app that is in a docker container, I have to always remember to add the module in the docker file. But if I centralize all module imports that will make the docker build more efficient.

Can any experienced python devs fill me in on the pitfalls.

I understand about using a requirements file but that's only for downloading, I want to centralize imports for docker builds and for actual code imports.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to include a `locals` module in an app that contains common imports.  Example of how the storm ORM does it:  https://github.com/petrhosek/storm/blob/master/storm/locals.py

This allows one to do:

```
from storm.locals import *
```

Comment: what's the cost of having a whole bunch of imports in a script that go unused?

Comment: @sirvon are you going to use the script?  If not then there is no cost.

Comment: yes, lets say i just dump all my imports in 1 file and then use that file in every script i construct for the app. is that behavior super costly?

Comment: in general you should only import the modules you are actually using in the script, otherwise it wastes memory.  As a convenience you can choose to import all used modules in the `locals` module, as described, but that will only do the imports once you import from it